# count the no. of matched values in resulted documents

Tags: mongodb

I working on a project where I want to find the similar type of values so I query my database and I want to count the matched values so that I can use the document which has maximum count.

I have written the almost query but unable to count the matched values which are in `$in` array

In the below code, I want to count the matched array values for every document

```
db.getCollection('combine_problems')
    .find({
        'answer':'United States',
        'book_id':{
            $nin:['103','102','101','105']
        },
        'choices': { 
            $in:  ['species', 'new habitat', 'range of species','United States' ] 
        }
    })
```

I want the matched document and the count value corresponding to every  document

Comment: Please refer the official documentation for MongoDB
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to have the count of documents in each `choices` you can simply do a grouping on `choices` and get a count but if want to append the `count of choices` with the above query you might have to use a script to get the expected output. Take a look at the process below:

Store the above query result in a variable let's say `docs` and add a `.toArray()`(*i.e. only if you have a small count of documents else don't use the `toArray()` and simply do a forEach on cursor and create a new object in the below forEach operation.*) to the end of the query, which will give you an array of objects containing key `choices`.

And then run another query where
 can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and do a [grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html)  on `choices` as:

```
db.getCollection('combine_problems').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { 'answer': 'United States' },
            {'book_id': {$nin: ['103', '102', '101', '105']}},
            {'choices': {$in: ['species', 'new habitat', 'range of species', 'United States']}
        ]
    }
},
{
    $group: { _id: "$choices", choice_count: { $sum: 1 } }

}])
```

Which will give a count of all the choices append the `.toArray()` to it as well and store the result in a variable let's say `counts` where you will get another array of objects containing 2 keys as `choices` and `choice_count`.

Later run the `foreach` on the first variable `docs` and append all the matching `choices` count from the `counts` object as:

```
docs.forEach(function(obj){
    var choice = obj['choices'];
    var choice_value = 0;
    counts.forEach(function(choice){
       if(choice['_id'] == choice)
       {
          choice_value = choice['choice_count'];
          break;
       }
    })
    obj['choice_count']=choice_value;
})
//to check if you have the count in the same document use print. 
print(JSON.stringify(docs));
```

Comment: the query doesn't give the accurate count of similar choices in some of the  document

Comment: @Anujtyagi check the result of the `group by` query', it should give you the result of all the choices and their count.